# Rails 4 nested attribute hash keys showing as unpermitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a `Category` model and a `Standard` model. A category has many standards through a "join table" model `CategoryStandard`. In my view, I have a form where I can edit the category description, and then add or remove standards from that category. So, my nested attributes are for `:category_standards`, because I'm not editing the standard itself, just adding or removing relationships, if that makes sense.

Here's the important part of the view:

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <%= label_tag nil, "Standards in this Category" %>
  <div id="standard-list">
    <%= f.fields_for :category_standards do |ff| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= ff.object.standard.number_with_exceptions %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :standard_id %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>".html_safe, "", class: "del-std-btn", title: "Remove standard from category" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="hidden" id="std-add-new-template">
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.fields_for :category_standards, CategoryStandard.new, child_index: "new_id" do |ff| %>
          <%= ff.collection_select :standard_id, @standards - @category.standards, :id, :number_with_exceptions, prompt: "Select a standard to add" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
...
<% end %>
```

There's some jQuery under the hood to manipulate the "rows", but that works fine and I don't think it's part of my problem, so I'll omit it.

In my Category model, I have:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_standards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :standards, through: :category_standards
  validates :description, presence: true,
                          uniqueness: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category_standards, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['standard_id'].blank?}
end
```

And in my Categories controller, I have:

```
def category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:description, category_standards_attributes: [:id, :standard_id, :_destroy])
end
```

But when I try to add a standard to a category, I get these lines in my server log (reformatted in the hopes of making it more readable):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
              "authenticity_token"=>"***********",
              "category"=>{
                "description"=>"Drinking Water System Components", 
                "category_standards_attributes"=>{
                  "0"=>{
                    "standard_id"=>"2",
                    "_destroy"=>"false",
                    "id"=>"1"
                  }, 
                  "new_id"=>{
                    "standard_id"=>""
                  },
                  "1424899001814"=>{
                    "standard_id"=>"1"
                  }
                }
              },
              "commit"=>"Save Changes",
              "id"=>"2"
            }

User Load (5.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

Category Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]

Unpermitted parameters: 0, new_id, 1424899001814

(4.0ms)  BEGIN
Category Exists (6.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."description" = 'Drinking Water System Components' AND "categories"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1

SQL (6.0ms)  UPDATE "categories" SET "description" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "categories"."id" = 2  [["description", "Drinking Water System Components"], ["updated_at", Wed, 25 Feb 2015 21:16:44 UTC +00:00]]
```

It updates the description field just fine, but what's up with the Unpermitted parameters? My attributes hash comes out just like the example in the Rails Guide on [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms), and it even says "The keys of the :addresses_attributes hash are unimportant, they need merely be different for each address." And yet it's the keys that are getting denied for me.

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, after a lot of reading. The missing piece was [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

> Hashes with integer keys are treated differently and you can declare the attributes as if they were direct children. You get these kinds of parameters when you use accepts_nested_attributes_for in combination with a has_many association:

```
# To whitelist the following data:
# {"book" => {"title" => "Some Book",
#             "chapters_attributes" => { "1" => {"title" => "First Chapter"},
#                                        "2" => {"title" => "Second Chapter"}}}}

params.require(:book).permit(:title, chapters_attributes: [:title])
```

The important part of that was "Hashes with **integer** keys". My hash keys were passing as "0", "new_id", "1240934304343". It isn't important that I use "new_id", because that's just a placeholder value that gets changed in my jQuery when new rows are added. Only the template row retains that value, which is fine, because it gets filtered out by my `reject_if` clause.

But the fact that "new_id" isn't an **integer** apparently was the thing that was mucking it all up. So I changed it to "-1", which Rails accepts (even though it is still filtered out by `reject_if`, as it should be).

```
<div class="hidden" id="std-add-new-template">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :category_standards, CategoryStandard.new, child_index: "-1" do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.collection_select :standard_id, @standards - @category.standards, :id, :number_with_exceptions, prompt: "Select a standard to add" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute keys don't seem to match what you are expecting in your strong parameters, "new_id" and "1424899001814" certainly will not be permitted.

```
"new_id"=>{
    "standard_id"=>""
},
"1424899001814"=>{
    "standard_id"=>"1"
}
```

I suspect the way you are constructing your form is invalid. Try breaking it down to the simplest working form.. like:

```
    <div id="standard-list">
        <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>".html_safe, "", class: "del-std-btn", title: "Remove standard from category" %>

        <div class="hidden" id="std-add-new-template">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.fields_for :category_standards do |ff| %>
                <%= ff.object.standard.number_with_exceptions %>
                <%= ff.hidden_field :standard_id %>
                <%= ff.hidden_field :_destroy %>
                <%= ff.collection_select :standard_id, @standards - @category.standards, :id, :number_with_exceptions, prompt: "Select a standard to add" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The intention is to have only one nested form, and by stripping it down create only one nested hash.

```
"category_standards_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{
        "standard_id"=>"2",
        "_destroy"=>"false",
        "id"=>"1"
    }
}
```

What happens with this?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. I still get the same type of error: `Unpermitted parameters: 0, new_id, 1424906638629`

Comment: thanks! I think you were on the right track, but I finally read something that gave me the "aha" moment. See my answer below.